# Plane "cloth" keeps falling off

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have a problem making the cloth sewing work. It keeps falling off. I have followed every instruction from a youtube video. I even looked at the clothweaver.com documentation for some answers. But It doesn't explain why some values works in a certain ways.

I had self-collision enabled from the the cloth. I even had the thickness outer and inner value to 0.010. How can I make the plane look like a real cloth without falling off? I'd appreciate your answers!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the "Sewing" checkbox from the Shape sub-menu in the cloth settings and then, when you bake or view the preview animation, it should pull the cloth pieces together.